# IndexOutOfBoundsException on FragmentManager.makeInactive

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` that uses a `SupportFragmentManager` to display a single fragment.

The Fragment has `n` child Fragments, using `getChildFragmentManager`.

I need to replace this Fragment with another one:

**Activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new MeetingFragment())
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}

public void refresh() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().clear();
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, new MeetingFragment())
            .commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

I tried adding this to my `MeetingFragment`, without success:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if (getChildFragmentManager().getFragments() != null) {
        getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().clear();
    }
}
```

Here is the `stacktrace`:

```
09-18 03:48:18.445      859-859/us.inevent.apps.demo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
            at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:477)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1261)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1168)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1304)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:695)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Do you have an idea what's happening?

Comment: where you are adding child fragments?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the onCreate method change the condition from

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
 //your code
}
```

to

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  //your code
 }
```